# MYSQL - Joining Multiple tables with COUNT()

Tags: mysql

I was asked to create a database for both students' tardiness and school policy's violations.

Now, I have three separate tables:

tbl_ClassList:

```
  Student_ID    Student_Name 
  1000          Lee, Jonder
  1001          Chow, Stephen
  1002          Kim, Martin
  1003          Johns, Kevin
  1004          Hearfield, Olivia
  1005          Jarrs, Marlon
```

tbl_Tardy:

```
  Record_No Student_ID
          1 1001 
          2 1001
          3 1000
          4 1003
          5 1002
          6 1003
          7 1001
          8 1001
          9 1002
         10 1004
```

tbl_Violation:

```
  Record_No Student_ID
          1 1000
          2 1000
          3 1004
          4 1005
          5 1001
          6 1002
          7 1003
```

What I was asked to do is to generate a list that combines that contains information about the students including his/her ID, name, number of tardiness and the number of violations. Something like this:

```
   Student_ID   Student_Name        No. of Tardy    No. of Violation
         1000   Lee, Jonder         1               2
         1001   Chow, Stephen       4               1
         1002   Kim, Martin         2               1
         1003   Johns, Kevin        2               1
         1004   Hearfield, Olivia   1               1
         1005   Jarrs, Marlon       0               1
```

Is there any type of Joins I can use to achieve the output? Please help me.

Comment: You can have a simple join and group by student id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find separate aggregates for tardy and violations inside subqueries and `left join` them with classlist table. Use `coalesce` to get zero in case there is no row for tardy/violation.

```
select c.*,
    coalesce(t.count_tardy, 0) as no_of_tardy,
    coalesce(v.count_violations, 0) as no_of_violations,
from tbl_classlist c
left join (
    select student_id,
        count(*) as count_tardy
    from tbl_tardy
    group by student_id
    ) t on c.student_id = t.student_id
left join (
    select student_id,
        count(*) as count_violations
    from tbl_violation
    group by student_id
    ) v on c.student_id = v.student_id;
```